# Optimizing Screenshot Capture Code in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a Unity project where I need to capture screenshots. I have the following code that works, but I'm looking for ways to make it run faster. Here's the code:

```
private IEnumerator InitSaveimageData()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    int width = Screen.width;
    int height = Screen.height;
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);

    tex.Apply();

    Texture2D tex2 = ScaleTexture(tex, width / 6, height / 6);

    byte[] bytes = tex2.EncodeToPNG();

    perviewImaege = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

    Texture2D.Destroy(tex); 

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

}

private Texture2D ScaleTexture(Texture2D source, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
    {
        Texture2D result = new Texture2D(targetWidth, targetHeight, source.format, true);
        Color[] sourcePixels = source.GetPixels();
        Color[] resultPixels = new Color[targetWidth * targetHeight];
        float ratioX = ((float)source.width / targetWidth);
        float ratioY = ((float)source.height / targetHeight);
        for (int y = 0; y < targetHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < targetWidth; x++)
            {
                int sourceIndex = (int)((y * ratioY) * source.width + x * ratioX);
                resultPixels[y * targetWidth + x] = sourcePixels[sourceIndex];
            }
        }
        result.SetPixels(resultPixels);
        result.Apply();
        return result;
    }
```

The code captures the screen, scales the image, converts it to PNG, and then saves the data. However, it seems to be running slower than I’d like.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to optimize this code to make it run faster?or some other way to saving the texture data? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.